# Python - como criar uma matriz bidimensional com laços for

Tags: python, for, array-multidimensional

Olá
O código mais abaixo dá a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Traceback (most recent call last): 
>     File "C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/testes python/vários.py", line 12, in 
>       mult[i][j] = (i*j)
>   IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Pergunto, quem está fora do range? i? j? O que se deve analisar (mudei todos os ranges com todos os valores possíveis) qdo se recebe essa mensagem (eu sei que significa que estaria tentando acessar um elemento fora dos limites estabelecidos), pois não vejo o que ou quem está fora.
Objetivo:[[0,0,0],[0,1,2],[0,2,4]...[0,10,20]]
Muito obrigado.

```
mult =[[] for _ in range(10)]

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(3):
        mult[i][j] = (i*j)

print(mult)
```

Comment: `i` quem está fora da faixa. Você possui penas uma lista contendo 10 outras listas vazias. Tente assim `print([[i*j for j in range(3)] for i in range(10)])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está criando uma lista contendo 10 elementos. Cada elemento dessa lista se trata de uma lista vazia, veja só:

```
x = [[] for _ in range(10)]
print(x)
```

Saida:

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Se você realmente quer uma array bidimensional vazia, sugiro algo como:

```
x = [[0 for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(10)]
print(x)
```

Saída:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Veja só como ficaria seu código:

```
mult = [[0 for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(10)]

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(3):
        mult[i][j] = (i*j)

print(mult)
```

Saída:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 4], [0, 3, 6], [0, 4, 8], [0, 5, 10], [0, 6, 12], [0, 7, 14], [0, 8, 16], [0, 9, 18]]
```

Para facilitar sua vida, você poderia implementar uma função capaz de gerar matrizes bidimensionais:

```
def createArray2D( xdim, ydim, default=0 ):
    return [[default for _ in range(xdim)] for _ in range(ydim)]

mult = createArray2D( 3, 10, 0 )

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(3):
        mult[i][j] = (i*j)

print(mult)
```

Ou então, usar a biblioteca padrão `numpy` para fazer o trabalho:

```
import numpy

mult = numpy.zeros((10, 3))

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(3):
        mult[i][j] = (i*j)

print(mult)
```

Saída:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  2.]
 [ 0.  2.  4.]
 [ 0.  3.  6.]
 [ 0.  4.  8.]
 [ 0.  5. 10.]
 [ 0.  6. 12.]
 [ 0.  7. 14.]
 [ 0.  8. 16.]
 [ 0.  9. 18.]]
```

Comment: Excelente, exemplos e explicação. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Essa sintaxe de atribuição `mult[i][j] = (i*j)` não vai funcionar na sua lista pois a `list` interna está vazia. Tente utilizar o método append como no exemplo abaixo

```py
mult =[[] for _ in range(10)]

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(3):
        mult[i].append(i*j)

print(mult)
```

O exemplo acima foi para utilizar o código do seu exemplo. Mas nem é preciso definir as posições com `mult =[[] for _ in range(10)]`. Com o uso do append é possível chegar ao mesmo resultado.

```py
mult =[]
for i in range(10):
    mult.append([])
    for j in range(3):
        mult[i].append(i*j)

print(mult)
```

Por fim você pode fazer abrangência de listas e colocar tudo isso em uma linha da seguinte forma:

```py
mult =[[i*j for j in range(3)] for i in range(10)]
```

Comment: Excelente. Muito obrigado.